# Need help to build hierarchical data by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, data-science

I have the CSV file content as below:

```
name_1,dept_code_1,name_2,dept_code_2,name_3,dept_code_3
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 1,CODE1-1,,
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 1,CODE1-1,ABC CHILD 1-1-1,CODE1-1-1
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 1,CODE1-1,ABC CHILD 1-1-2,CODE1-1-2
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 2,CODE1-2,ABC CHILD 1-2-1,CODE1-2-1
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 2,CODE1-2,ABC CHILD 1-2-2,CODE1-2-2
XYZ,CODE2,XYZ CHILD,CODE2-2,,
```

I would like to build the hierarchical data with this logic:

- *name_1,dept_code_1*: **the parent**
- *name_2,dept_code_2*: **child of 1 (parent)**
- *name_3,dept_code_3*: **child of 2**

CSV file may have more columns: **name_4,dept_code_4 ... name_n,dept_code_n**

Expected output of above CSV:

```
ABC,CODE1,,,,,OK
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 1,CODE1-1,,,OK
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 1,CODE1-1,ABC CHILD 1-1-1,CODE1-1-1,OK
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 1,CODE1-1,ABC CHILD 1-1-2,CODE1-1-2,OK
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 2,CODE1-2,,,OK
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 2,CODE1-2,ABC CHILD 1-2-1,CODE1-2-1,OK
ABC,CODE1,ABC CHILD 2,CODE1-2,ABC CHILD 1-2-2,CODE1-2-2,OK
XYZ,CODE2,,,,,OK
XYZ,CODE2,XYZ CHILD,CODE2-1,,,OK
```

Would anyone guide me the best practice to do this by Python?

This is the code that I'm trying:

```html
import os
import csv

from io import StringIO

with open(os.path.join('', 'test.csv')) as csv_file:
    content = StringIO(csv_file.read())
    csv_rows = csv.DictReader(content, delimiter=',')
    final_data = {}
    for row in csv_rows:
        if row['name_1']:
            if row['name_1'] not in final_data:
                final_data[row['name_1']] = {}
                final_data[row['name_1']]['dept_code_1'] = row['dept_code_1']
        if row['name_2']:
            if row['name_2'] not in final_data[row['name_1']]:
                final_data[row['name_1']][row['name_2']] = {}
                final_data[row['name_1']][row['name_2']]['dept_code_2'] = row['dept_code_2']
        if row['name_3']:
            if row['name_3'] not in final_data[row['name_1']][row['name_2']]:
                final_data[row['name_1']][row['name_2']][row['name_3']] = {}
                final_data[row['name_1']][row['name_2']][row['name_3']]['dept_code_3'] = row['dept_code_3']

    print(final_data)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you demonstrate that you are *also* working to solve your problem. The best way to do that is to include the __text__ of code you have tried even if it is not working quite right. If you have no idea how to get started, check out the `collections` module, specifically `collections.defaultdict` and or the built-in dictionary method `setdefault()`

Comment: @JonSG: Thank you for your comment. I added the code that I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at **itertools.groupby**

```
import os
import csv

from io import StringIO
from itertools import groupby

with open(os.path.join('', 'test.csv')) as csv_file:
    content = StringIO(csv_file.read())
    csv_rows = csv.DictReader(content, delimiter=',')

    group_by_dept_code_1 = groupby(csv_rows, lambda n: n['dept_code_1'])
```